# how to get UTC date time from internet in order to check if the device time is correct or not

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

The scenario is I want to keep the device time correct if the device time is incorrect then I want to change it to the correct time0.

In order to do this I have 3 challenges:

**1 challenge:**
get device UTC time.

**2 challenge:**
get correct UTC time from the internet

**3 challenge:**
if the time is not correct then make it correct

I am able to complete 1 challenge by using the code given below:

```
 NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:timeZone];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *dateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate: [NSDate date]];
```

how ever I need your help to complete other two challenges. Please help

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear why you want to do this as the OS (name your favourite) already performs this function. This is done using NTP, the Network Time Protocol. You can start at [The Network Time Protocol](http://www.ntp.org) website to understand how it works and what you'll need to do.

HTH